# What is best practice for displaying avatar image in terms of users logging in with facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

We are using facebook login on our website and don't know if it is better to actually store the user avatar image on our servers and serve from there or just serve them using the graph API?

I understand the graph API will be more convenient since it will always bring the most up to date photo but I assume there will be restrictions?

Can someone please explain what is best practice when it comes to this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the user's image on your DB would add another level of complexity to your application.

What I would suggest is just use the Graph API. It would always return the most current Display Picture of the user and it wouldn't be restricted as it is public data.

The only thing you have to worry about is getting access to THAT public data by having the user Login Using Facebook on your website. You can only access the user's image if the user is logged in to your application.

Once you have that out of the way, you can now have access to the User Image with ease.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Here are 2 things I am thinking. Sometimes users want to login with FB but not necessarily use FB profile photo. The second one is, will there be restrictions on Graph API in terms of pinging it for photos if the site gets a lot of traffic.

Comment: For the 1st one, if they agree to Login using facebook, Im not sure if they can possibly disable the ability for the application to get their Photo. Their photo is public information.

2nd one, not that I know of. I haven't heard of any restrictions with regards to accessing the user's photo. The only limit I know is the amount of API calls, and getting the photo using it's URL does not count as one. So yeah, its safe to say that there wouldn't be a limit for accessing the User's photo from facebook's given image URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I marked your answer as the correct one now with the explanations.